# PostgreSQL - copy first 5 rows of all tables and output to a file

Tags: postgresql

I need to grab the first 5 rows of every table in PostgreSQL and output them to my computer in .csv and (preferably) .sql. There are 275 total tables.

Is this possible to do via CLI in a single scripted command?

So far I'm able to copy a single table at a time, but it's taking forever.

```
\COPY (SELECT * from table-name limit 5) TO '/vagrant/testexport.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Yes: it is possible. Please define *first* first.

Comment: At present I'm using the following, which works but is limited to one table at a time: \COPY (SELECT * from table-name limit 5) TO '/vagrant/testexport.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Comment: `\copy` is `psql` client side command. so the script should be shell. what OS u use?..

Comment: Ah, thanks. @VaoTsun I'm using Ubuntu linux (via Vagrant)

Answer (score 1):

bash file:

```
tables=$(psql -d a -tXa -c "COPY(select concat(schemaname,'.',tablename) as tables from pg_tables) to '/tmp/tlist'")
for i in $(cat /tmp/tlist); do
        psql -d a -tXa -c "\COPY (SELECT * from $i limit 5) TO '/tmp/$i.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;";
done
```